# How do I get the classname of an aspx page from inside a user control?

Tags: asp.net, reflection

I would like to assertain the class name of an aspx page from within a user control.  How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
this.Page.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Answer (score 11):

### Page.GetType().BaseType.Name;

It's Give Class Name of Page.

### Page.GetType().BaseType.FullName;

It's Give you Class Name with namespace.

Comment: Just `Page.GetType().BaseType` gives you a clean "Namespace.ClassName" as defined at the top of your .aspx.cs (the same classname the .aspx page inherits)

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of a use case but try:

```
string name = Page.GetType().Name;
```